# Sampling population U to rank elements of another population S

Tags: sampling

I have two sets of locations(lat/long pairs), U and S. I have to count
how many elements of U fall within a 10 mile radius of each location
in S i.e. construct a circle of radius 10 miles at each of the
location in set S and count how many elements of U fall within those
circles. This is to be done so that I can determine the top 100 most
dense locations in S.

Problem is that this count will take a very long time if I brute force
it. I don't have a lot of compute power available to me. U has 100
million entries while S has 1 million entries. It takes about 25 hours
for 1000 locations of S i.e. entire U and only first 1000 entries of
S.

Set U is comprised of data collected over an entire month (30 days). I
plan to take 10,000 samples from each of the day (uniform random
selection) to get a 300,000 subset of U and do the count for all the
entries in S. Now if I take the top 200 locations found in this way,
what is the chance that this set will contain the actual top 100 dense
locations? The reason I want to take 200(or more) locations is to
compensate for sampling and other approximations.

Needless to say I don't have a formal training in statistics. I just
want to use a sample to find a smaller set of locations that might
contain the most dense locations to a high degree of likelihood.

Questions:

Will this work?

How should I estimate the sample size? Is 10,000 samples per day
enough? More samples mean more compute time, so there is a trade-off
here.

What topics should I investigate in the field of statistics to gain
more understanding of how to solve this problem?

Comments:

I am not bothered with overlap of counts at the moment.

I suspect the title question does not make much sense to a statistics savvy reader.